# How to change thymeleaf static content default path in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to change CSS and JS default path from the resource to something else for thymeleaf.

I am using JSP as a view instead of thymeleaf but for email template, I decided to go with thymeleaf, in every search I saw spring boot by default looks into resource /static folder is there any way to force spring boot to look into another folder outside resource.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple resource folder you can add those in your classpath by extending `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` class like below. have a try

@Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @ComponentScan
    public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

```
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {

        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();

        String[] strBaseNames = {
                 "ca.gc.myproject.global.myResources", //full class path of your folder
                 "ca.gc.myproject.user.yourResources",
        };


        return messageSource;
    }
}
```

source :[https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot](http://source)